# Implementation of Message Bus C# microservices

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core-1.0, message-bus

We have few micro services created in .net core 1.0, we are following CQRS pattern and we are also using swagger which list all api's, we have a requirement were in we need to implement Message Bus(not decided yet might be AWS), this message bus will orchestrate UI operations, that spans across multiple backend services, so I don't know how to start because I 'm new to this, I need to understand message bus, queues, publishing events to message bus so could you please help me to understand?
Also any pointers to tutorial videos and so on with explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Any help will be much appreciated..

Comment: I can recommend reading: http://www.benstopford.com/2018/04/27/book-designing-event-driven-systems/

Answer (score 1):

You would read this [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/integration-event-based-microservice-communications) from Maira Wenzel at Microsoft. It helped me a lot on my beginning days.

> An event bus allows publish/subscribe-style communication between microservices without requiring the components to explicitly be aware of each other

Answer (score 1):

In a microservice architecture, Services should not communicate with each other in a synchronous way, instead, all services need to communicate via Message-Brocker. There are lots of messages brokers like RabbitMq, Kafka and so on which you can use them.

Using a message broker directly needs to manage all of the details related to message brokers' behaviors and need lots of code to do that. So here Service-Bus comes to the story.

The service bus is an intermediate between each service and message broker to encapsulate all details and configurations in the Message broker. So microservice blocks (each bounded context in DDD) could communicate with each other simply and in a high-level manner.
[image]

The point is in the service bus you just get rid of message broker complexities. So you don't need to worry about low-level concepts like the type of exchanges, queues, and so on in message broker.
I just have tried to give you high-level information, But in fact, Message Bus could do lots of other things.

Comment: Great answer. There are ready made packages like NServiceBus, MassTransit, Rebus, Wolverine, etc. They work on Azure Service Bus, RabbitMQ, etc. One note: Kafka is not a message broker, but an event streaming platform. Message brokers are most of the time used for business events, internal communication within a system. Even streaming platforms are often used for massive amounts of events, like absorbing events from large amount of IoT devices.